# GCC plugin for list the source file from binary

Tags: gcc, gcc-plugins

I would to like ask this question, **whether gcc is having "plugin" which can list the source file from binary file (binary is not stripped) ??**
 If plugin is not available, then could anyone please guide me "how to implement the same as gcc features.

Comment: Is there any feasibility to implement the same.?

Comment: It is not what GCC about -- GCC is compiler, not decompiler. This "plugin" is called "objdump with source annotations".

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov: Thanks for your reply. yes, you are absolutely correct, same can be achieved through **objdump** and **gdb** as well.But as per my requirement it has to through **gcc**. so can we done same through gcc (Is there any feasibility to achieved same)